# Delphi Outlook Contact Automation - Iterate thru ALL properties of a ContactItem

Tags: delphi, properties, outlook, automation, contacts

I am currently writing a small program to extract ALL data elements of my Outlook contacts to a new CRM database.  I have imported the necessary type library and came up with the following code (It's almost there!!!)

`

```
 Contacts := NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts);

  for i := 1 to Contacts.Items.Count do
  begin
    Contact := Contacts.Items.Item(i);
    {now you can read any property of contact. For example, full name and
     email address}
//    ShowMessage(Contact.FullName + ' <' + Contact.Email1Address + '>');
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Contact.FullName + ' <' + Contact.Email1Address + '>');
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Contact.ItemProperties.Count) + '>');

for j := 0 to Contact.ItemProperties.Count -1 do
 if Contact.ItemProperties.Item(j) <> null then
   Memo1.Lines.Add(Contact.ItemProperties.Item(j));
```

end;

Iterating thru the contacts works OK (I see them in the Memo).  My problem is the 2nd "for" loop in trying to check ALL 168 fields of the contact (the 168 shows in the memo too)

Can anyone help shed some light on iterating thru each Property of each contact item?  I have found some answers but I need/want to drill down further.

Thanks in advance

Bill

Comment: I doubt that Contact.ItemProperties.Item(j) will succesfully translate every Variant to a string. What if  a property is an array? I suggest using VarIsNull, then detect the variant type and handle conversions aprpopriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after spending some quality time in the TLB for office I was able to walk the properties of each contact whether useful or not.  The RTFBody property had to be converted from Unicode to ANSI WideString, the attachments as a collection (count was there so easy enough to iterate), and dispatch values I just bypassed.  Learned a lot, MSDN Office Interop online docs provided good help in handling field types. The long handed dot notation was necessary because I could not seem to get grouping to work but stepping down each level worked just fine.  The important parts follow.  As always thanks for the input.

```
 Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Contacts.Items.Count) + '>');
 for i := 1 to Contacts.Items.Count do
  begin
    Contact := Contacts.Items.Item(i);
  {now you can read any property of contact. For example, full name and
    email address}

    for j := 0 to Contact.ItemProperties.Count -1 do
     begin
      ContactProperty := Contact.ItemProperties.Item(j);
      if not VarIsNull(ContactProperty.Value) then

       if ContactProperty.Name = 'RTFBody' then
        begin
         RTFByte := ContactProperty.Value;
         SetString(tANSIStr, PAnsiChar(@RTFByte[0]), Length (ContactProperty.Value));
         Memo1.Lines.Add(ContactProperty.Name + ' <' + tANSIstr +  '>');
         RichEdit1.Lines.Add(tANSIstr);
        end
       else

       if ContactProperty.Name = 'Attachments' then
        begin
         Attachments := Contact.Attachments;
         for k := 1 to Attachments.Count do
          begin
           ContactAttachment := Attachments.Item(k);
           Memo1.Lines.Add('Attachment.FileName <' + ContactAttachment.FileName +  '>');
          end;
        end
     end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison to null in that way might be the problem. Try:

```
for j := 0 to Contact.ItemProperties.Count -1 do
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Contact.ItemProperties.Item(j).Name);
```

or even:

```
for j := 0 to Contact.ItemProperties.Count -1 do
  if Contact.ItemProperties.Item(j).Name <> null then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Contact.ItemProperties.Item(j).Name);
```

I am not sure but you can even try to access the items in ItemProperties like:

```
Contact.ItemProperties[j].Name
```

Comment: VarIsNull worked great - Thanks to Jan & Blurry for the tag team!